# Does Facebook SDK & APIs access iDevices UDID?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, udid

As with recent cases of AppStore rejecting apps that are accessing UDIDs, does Facebook SDK & APIs access iDevices UDID?  Kindly advise. Thank you!

Comment: No facebook api doesn't use your UDID. kindly read the document on facebook developer page for more detail.

Comment: check out this [Developer Reference for FACEBOOK API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/) for more detail

Comment: meanwhile you can check if any of your third party framework uses it by invoking following code in terminal `strings yourLibName.a | grep uniqueIdentifier`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed the newest Facebook IOS SDK 3.5.1 still uses the String "uniqueIdentifier" as you can see, when you use the command

```
cd facebook-ios-sdk/
strings FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK | grep uniqueIdentifier
```

Unfortunately this causes any app that uses the Facebook SDK to be rejected in the first step and being flagged "Invalid Binary".  Without uploading you can verify this already in the Xcode Organizer - Archives, using the Validate function.

So, yes it is a problem, and any hint to solve this is welcome!

Some more research on this issue:

I checked the sources of facebook ios sdk 3.5.1 on [github](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Actually there is no reference to the identifier "uniqueIdentifier" in the sources.  The only library that is used is the **Accounts.framework** from the IOS itself. So it looks like Apple themselves have to update their library!!

Comment: Facebook admit to it here: http://developers.facebook.com/ios/change-log-3.x/ "Usage of UIDevice to prevent false positives regarding [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] for App Store approval."

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an older version of the facebook-ios-sdk, but it doesn't appear to be accessing the UDID. The proper way to get the UDID on iOS is to call

```
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

If you're using the facebook sdk, it gives you access to the source code.  So, you can search through the source code, and see if the **uniqueIdentifier** message is used.  On UNIX (or OS X terminal), you can try:

```
   cd facebook-ios-sdk/
   find . -name '*.m' | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier
```

This didn't turn up any hits with the version of the SDK I was using (about a year old).

There's definitely some more diabolical ways to access functions to avoid easy detection (such as my use of UNIX grep), but Apple has approved lots of apps that use this SDK.  I think you're safe.